# Android font picker example?

Tags: android, fonts, picker

I'm looking to implement a font picker for my Android app.  I already found some nice color pickers, can anybody point me to an example of a font picker that I can pop into my app?

Comment: Although the answer below is a valid approach and the link is also helpful, I ended up using a spinner to present my font options.

Comment: If you are using Jetpack Compose, you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72519599/11004423) answer usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty simple to make one using a ListView. Each row in the list could simply be a TextView where the text is set to the name of the font and the typeface used is the actual font.

There doesn't need to be anything special about the listview. A simple listview with an ArrayAdapter should be sufficient.  Using an adapter like this should work.

**NOTE** this code isn't meant to compile rather to illustrate what you would need to do to solve the problem. It should be enough though to get you started.

```
public class FontListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter< String >
{

    public FontListAdapter(Activity context,  String[] title, boolean[] isHeader) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitem, title);
        this.context = context;
        this.isHeader = isHeader;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        TextView t;
        if (convertView==null)
            t = new TextView(parent.getContext());
        else
            t = (TextView) convertView;

        t.setText(getFontName());
        t.setTypeface(getFont());
        return convertView;
    }
    public Typeface getFont(int pos){
        TypeFace tf = getTypeFaceForThisPosition(pos); // you need to figure this out
        return tf;
    }
    public String getFontName(int pos){
        String fontName = getFontNameForThisPosition(pos); // you need to figure this out
        return FontName;
    }
}
```

Also you can look at this:
http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.0/development/apps/FontLab/src/com/android/fontlab/FontPicker.java

Comment: -1 - your code won't even compile. Leaving alone the fact that the user probably wants to pick primarily among system fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link, I'll have to check the code before I can really say anything conclusive there.

Comment: @Seva, The code wasnt meant to be complete, let alone compile. I didnt have the time to code up a completely functional example, rather i wanted to point the op in the right direction. The PSUEDO code above was meant to functionailty that he would need to implement if he wanted to create his own font picker.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, For the record, the last link he posted looks really good (although, it's a super slow loading page, so be patient or copy it off from the google cache). That one should compile just fine as long as Alan writes the corresponding layout file.

Comment: Well, not only is this the best answer I got... it's the only one, so I'm giving it to you!

Comment: that means it also the worst answer you go too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This looks promissing:

Enumerating the fonts on Android platform
http://www.ulduzsoft.com/2012/01/enumerating-the-fonts-on-android-platform/

FontPreference dialog for Android
http://www.ulduzsoft.com/2012/01/fontpreference-dialog-for-android/